# Numeros aleatorios dentro de um vetor em C

Tags: c, array, random

Ola gostaria de saber qual seria o metodo ideal para gerar numeros aleatorios dentro de um vetor em C utilizando a funcao rand(), eu obtenho um erro quando tento rodar o codigo abaixo.

segue o codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define vMax 5

main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int vetor[vMax] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < vMax; i++){
        printf("%d",vetor[i]);
    }
}
```

o erro basicamente diz que o array precisa ser inicializado com chaves porem quando eu coloco as chaves ele tmb me retorna OUTRO erro, entao logicamente nao seria este o jeito de gerar elementos aleatorios do vetor. Agradeço desde já, todo comentário estará me ajudando no aprendizado.

Comment: pode não ser isto, mas tenta colocar assim: `int vetor[vMax] = rand() % (10 + 1);`

Comment: @IanMoone Sua solucao retorna erro, mas obrigado por agregar ao topico

Comment: Note que quando você faz: int vetor[vMax] = rand() % 10 + 1; você está fazendo uma atribuição ao elemento de índice vMax, contudo os índices válidos para seu vetor variam de 0 a vMax-1. Você está acessando uma posição de memória fora da área reservada para seu vetor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porque você não tem algo assim :

```
main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int vetor[vMax];
    for(int i = 0; i < vMax; i++){
        vetor[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nossa nao pensei nisso, porem agora tenho elementos repetidos, como resolveria isso?

Comment: Quando eu fazia trabalhos assim na faculdade eu percorria todo o vetor verificando se X  valor já não tinha sido adicionado, se sim, gerava outro valor, se não, adicionava ele na posição I do vetor.
Eu sei, grosseira a solução rsrsrs